# How to insert an element on all my views?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want every view on my MVC3 application to render a tag

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<url>" />
```

How can I make all views insert this tag? Where should I place the code?

<sub>(I am guessing I can put somewhere that is not the Master View)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put it in the Master Page (ASPX views) or Layout page (Razor views).

If you want to, you can render it in the Master/Layout page using a Child Action.

Comment: Yeah, basically you should look at how the masterpage/layoutpage renders the `<title></title>`-tag, and do something similar.